# JavaScript: Alert not working in the script

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. This is my second day to start actual learning of JavaScript. I don't know if it is appropriate place to ask this question because there are so many guidelines and standards to follow.

Well, here what I wrote a little script and it is not working. When `value < 5 && value > 5` it is showing alerts. But when someone gave the answer 5 (which is the correct answer). It is not showing any alert? I tried myself to resolve this problem but I couldn't resolve this problem. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var number = prompt("count these numbers: 2+5-10+8=?");
    if( number === 5 ) {
     alert( "Congratulations Your Answer is Correct" );
    }
    else if ( number > 5  ) {
      alert( "Your answer is a little higher." );
    }
    else if ( number < 5 ) {
      alert( "Your answer is little lower than actual answer." );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: [You should definitely use jQuery on this one.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)

Comment: @Azib - Since you're new to JavaScript, I want to point out that Derek is joking ;)

Answer (score 8):

The prompt is returning a string, but you're doing a strict equal test for a number.

You can...

- Test for a string instead with `number === "5"`,
- or use `==` instead of `===`, which will do a conversion for you,
- or convert the prompt to a number with `number = parseInt(number, 10)`
- or if you'll potentially be testing for floats, use `number = parseFloat(number)`

Comment: @AzibYaqoob: Be careful with that one. If the number you're testing for is `0`, and the user passes an empty string, it'll show up as a positive match.

Comment: So, I need to make another alert for this. If user left the form empty then the new alert message alert show instead of < or > alerts, right?

Comment: @AzibYaqoob: All depends on what you actually need to validate. Yes, you could test for an empty string separately. If you want to ensure that it's a valid numeric string, you could do `number = parseInt(number, 10)`, and the do a test to see if it parsed into a number correctly. `if (isNaN(number)) { alert("Not a valid number!"); }`

Comment: @amnotiam - Or use `+"5"` for lazy people like me.

Comment: Don't use `parseInt` unless you are happy for `5asd` to be accepted as correct.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
var number = parseInt(prompt("count these numbers: 2+5-10+8=?"),10);
```

Comment: You were ahead of me on the `parseInt` +1

Comment: Not a good answer, using `parseInt` means that answers like `5asda` will be accepted as correct. Much simpler to use the equality operator `==`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a '===' comparison, it checks if the types exactly match up, and in this case youre checking if the NUMBER 5 is equal to the STRING 5 (or whatever else they entered), which is false.

You need to parse the answer into an integer, as David Thomas has already suggested:

```
var number = parseInt(prompt("count these numbers: 2+5-10+8=?"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use `==` instead of strict equality `===`.

Don't use `parseInt` as it will convert say `5iasd` to `5`, so you'll either accept incorrect answers or need an extra test.

Don't use `parseFloat` as it isn't required.  Using `==` means that all of the following return true:

```
var n = 5;

n == '5'
n == '5.0'
n == '5e0'
n == '0.5e1'
```

and so on.

Oh, for reference, you should learn how the ECMAScript [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) works.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertmsg", "alert('your message');", true);
```